# Is there a way to copy Windows user folders with the shutil.copy2() method?

Tags: python, shutil

I have created a Python script, whose goal is to copy Windows user folders (Downloads, Desktop, Music and so on...) to a USB drive.

```
def copyFolders():
   userPath = f"C:\\Users\\{user}\\"
   priorityLs = ["Music", "Documents", "Desktop", "Downloads", "Pictures", "Videos"]
   permissionErrors = 0
   permissionGrant = 0
   removedElems = 0

   for i in range(len(priorityLs)):
      print("Copying...")
      try: copy2(userPath+priorityLs[i], usbDrive)
      except PermissionError: print(Fore.RED+f"Permission error! {Fore.WHITE[{userPath+priorityLs[i]}]{Fore.RESET}"); permissionErrors += 1
      else: permissionGrant += 1

   print(f"Permission grants: {permissionGrant} | Permission errors: {permissionErrors} | Removed elements: {removedElems}")
```

However, upon execution, I keep getting *PermissionError*.
This confuses me, since even running the script with administrator rights throws the error, and those folders aren't encrypted.

Malware is easily capable of accessing to those folders to cipher them.

I have tried, as I mentionned above to run the script as admin, but same thing.
Literally no folder can be copied.

I have looked at a question, asking why shutil.copy2 cannot copy to different drives, but it has no answers.

Here is the error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "e:\Code\Python\mainscr.py", line 152, in <module>
    copyFolders()   File "e:\Code\Python\mainscr.py", line 108, in copyFolders
    copy2(userPath+priorityLs[i], usbDrive)   File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 434, in copy2
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)   File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 254, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\name\\Videos'
```

Comment: Your `try`/`except` is masking what the actual problem is.  You should get rid of that until the code is working 100%.  Otherwise, you're just stabbing in the dark.  BTW, the `robocopy` command can do what you ask simply and reliably, no programming required, and it can even log its results.

Comment: I will provide an update when I can remove the try/except block.

Comment: I added the traceback.

Comment: You're using `shutil.copy2`.  That accepts a filename as its first parameter, not a directory name.  Perhaps you should look into using `os.walk` to copy the files individually.  Or, use an existing command line tool.